# only show the sum of all the id that have transacted in the past 12 months

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
select
id
,id_name
, MAX(last_login_date)
, SUM(transaction_count)
, mAX(last_transaction_date)
from sales;
```

hi I am looking for the results to only include a transaction count for the sales made in the last 12 months. what can I do?

I have **max** and **sum** because there are multiple instances of the same ids so they are not unique.

I don't have individual transaction dates. I only have a last transaction date field

Answer (score 1):

You may use `months_between` function to have 12 months directly :

```
select id,id_name, MAX(last_login_date), SUM(transaction_count), mAX(last_transaction_date)
  from sales
 where months_between(trunc(sysdate),last_transaction_date) <= 12
 group by id, id_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to select all transactions in a month (with current month), you can use this construction:

```
select id
     , id_name
     , Max(last_login_date)
     , Sum(transaction_count)
     , Max(last_transaction_date)
  from sales
 where last_transaction_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-11)
 group by id, id_name;
```